# Is it possible to have a global parameter page which allows to configure other plugins in the same place?

Tags: options, settings-api, page-specific-settings

I have a wordpress mu installation which brings together several different sites for clients and I would like to provide them with a settings page to manage the settings of other plugins.
In short, I would like to have in a global parameter page, the possibility to configure in the same place, some options of the Yoast SEO plugin and the WooCommerce plugin for example.

How can I start this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: From a certain perspective, it makes sense to use the Frontend-Customizer, that's what it is made for. You can implement all settings into different sections (for 3rd party plugins in your case). Some cool custom controls can be found here: https://github.com/maddisondesigns/customizer-custom-controls. These settings can be read everywhere in the theme with get_theme_mod().

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am looking at this solution to see what it gives.